# Functoriality of twisted de Rham Cohomology

Tags: differential-forms, vector-bundles, functors, de-rham-cohomology

Let $f: M\to N$ be a smooth map of finite-dimensional manifolds, and let $E\to N$ be a flat vector bundle over $N$. Consider the pullback bundle $f^*E\to M$ over $M$ and consider the twisted de Rham-cohomology groups 
$$ H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(N,E)$$

as they are defined in *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by R. Bott and L. W. Tu. I was wondering whether $f$ induces a homomorphism
$$ f^*: H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(N,E)\to H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(M,f^*E).$$
I tried to take an element $u_p\otimes e_p\in\bigwedge^k T_p^*N\otimes E_p$ and to map it to $f^*u_p\otimes e_p$. The problem is that $e_p$ is not necessarily an element of $f^*E$. So, my questions are:

1. Is $f^*$ well-defined with the definition above?
2. If it isn't, is there another way to obtain some kind of "functoriality"; possibly using a different vector bundle over $M$ or over $N$?

Comment: Why do not you considering $f^{*}e_p$?

Comment: As far as I understand, there is a map $f^*: f^*E\to E$, but not the other way round. Am I misunderstanding something?